# UIPopovercontroller Flip animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

Can we flip  UIPopovercontroller horizontally so as to load a new subview view?

Is it possible to achieve an animation which does:

1. Load small view in UIpoovercontroller first and on a click of a button in popover
2. Flip UIpoovercontroller and loads a model view

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to set the `modalPresentationStyle` of your second controller to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`, and its `modalTransitionStyle` to `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`.

Comment: Hey Simon,Thanks for the reply. But my question is about popovercontroller. Can we animate uipopovercontroller along with the view inside so as to show a model view.?

Comment: Not easily.  But if you do as I suggested, you can flip over the view inside the popover.

Comment: It's actually only possible to present a view controller in a popover using the vertical cover transition.